# User login failing on Azure website

Tags: azure, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

I have a production and development version of a website on an Azure server.  Both of the connect to the same Membership Database.

Currently, the sites are still identical.  The username/login combination works correctly on the production site, but gives an incorrect username/password combination error on the development site.

I am also able to login in through localhost, which is hitting the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to explicitly set machine key in your application's web.config. Otherwise, Azure will create one automatically.

If machine key is different, the existing user might not be able to login anymore.

Comment: I had the machine key set explicitly, though I definitely looked at that.
The issue turned out to be that when I was publishing the site, there was an option, to "replace" the connection string in the web.config of the publish location.  This was replacing the connection string to the Membership Database, with the connection to the main database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the machine key set explicitly, though I definitely looked at that. The issue turned out to be that when I was publishing the site, there was an option, to "replace" the connection string in the web.config of the publish location. This was replacing the connection string to the Membership Database, with the connection to the main database.